# ¿Cómo hago que un usuario conceda privilegios otros usuarios?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, data

```
CREATE ROLE 'DECANO_FACULTAD', 'DIRECTOR_CARRERA','DOCENTE';
CREATE ROLE 'ADMINISTRADOR', 'SECRETARIO', 'JEFE_SISTEMAS_FACULTAD';
GRANT ALL ON mydb TO 'DECANO_FACULTAD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL ON mydb TO 'ADMINISTRADOR' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Entiendo que para que un usuario pueda conceder privilegios hay que hacerlo con WITH GRANT OPTION, ¿pero ahora cómo hago para concederlos?
Ejemplo, que el ADMINISTRADOR conceda permisos al SECRETARIO.

Comment: Si tú tienes el Superusuario puedes conceder los privilegios a todos los usuarios según se requiera. Ahora, si quieres que el Administrador conceda al Sectario pues debes darle privilegios de superusuario. Pero no creo que sea buena idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer de varias maneras

**Esto da permisos globales.**

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'SECRETARIO'@'LOCALHOST';
```

**Esto da permisos globales a nivel de las bases de datos de almacen.**

```
GRANT ALL ON ALMACEN.* TO 'SECRETARIO'@'LOCALHOST';
```

**Permite a este usuario dar estos permisos a otros usuarios.**

```
GRANT ALL ON ALMACEN.* TO 'SECRETARIO'@'LOCALHOST' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**Crear usuarios sin privilegios.**

```
GRANT USAGE ON *:* TO anonimo IDENTIFIED BY “clave”;
```

**Y una vez dado el permiso lo debes aplicar con.**

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta no te olvides de darle al check para cerrar este hilo